# MySql query not giving desired result

Tags: mysql

**Schema:**

```
[Analysed table]-(runId,resultId,bugId)    
[Bug Table]-(bugId,bugType)    
[Runs]-(runId,failCount)
```

**Query :**

```
select bugId,bugType,failCount 
from Bug,Runs 
inner join (select runId from Analysed where bugId=118)counts on counts.runId=Runs.runId
```

I am not getting required result.I am getting null output.

What I want is for RunId=118 I want all Bug Table details and failure count(from Runs table).

I am not sure whether we require Analysed table or not.

Comment: Don't mix implicit and explicit join syntax

Comment: I didn't get you,please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use join, you have to do it for every table:

```
select bugId,bugType,failCount 
from Bug inner join Runs on <condition>
inner join (select runId from Analysed where bugId=118)counts on counts.runId=Runs.runId
```

Comment: But there is no condition for Bug inner join Runs

Comment: What I want is for RunId=118 I want all Bug Table details and failure count(from Runs table).

Comment: @TRY123 Can you please add some sample data?

Comment: Sample data for the query ?

Comment: I can't post pictures..minimum 10 reputation needed.